# Execute a bash function inside a detached screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, gnu-screen

I want to execute single function from the whole script into a detached screen session rather than to run the whole script inside screen. Can someone tell anyway how can I do it?
Like for example

```
#!/bin/bash

fun1(){
     echo "hii1"
}
fun2(){
     echo "Hii2"
}
delete(){
     rm -rf boom.txt
}
fun3(){
while do
lol=$(cat abcd.txt)
if (( lol=1 )); then
$(delete)
break
fi
done
```

Like I want only fun3 should be run inside a detached screen session. How can this be done?

Comment: `screen -dm COMMAND`. Any reason you want to use `screen` instead of a simple trailing `&`?

Answer (score 0):

As the script only defines the functions and does nothing else, you can
first execute the script within the context of the current shell using the `source` or `.` command and then simply call the function:

```
source myScript.sh && fun3
```

Comment: Its just a example script, I cannot post the main script due to my company policies. I just want to run a function inside a detached screen session

Comment: @ph3ro nobody asked you to do that, but if you fail to elaborate if this answer works or not, nobody can help you.

Comment: Obviously sir this answer won't work in my case

Comment: You should explain more why it doesn't work and what you lack to make it work. Editing your post would be preferable over commenting.